# Is there an IEEE or ISO standard for representing 1/3 exactly?

Tags: types, standards

Floating point math has quirks for representing whole fractions in data-interchange.

When you have a set of percentages that tries communicates 100%, you end up making concessions to represent one or more of the numbers.

3 shareholders with 1/3 each, you have 0.333, 0.333 and 0.334

2 shareholders with 1/3 and 2/3, you have 0.333 and 0.667

Is representing a 'share' as a 'percent' by using a floating point number an inherently flawed approach?

Is there a standard for representing fractional shares exactly that could be used?

Answer (score 0):

No to both questions.

1. It's inherently limited, not inherently flawed. It only becomes flawed when someone doesn't respect the limits.
2. There's no standard. There are several existing libraries that can be used, but none officially blessed.

Comment: I know SO isn't about suggesting libraries, but would you care to cite a few libraries?
Boost.Rational - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/rational/

Comment: @JJS [No problemo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html).